# NodeJS: Execute a function when UTC server time equals to time entry in firebase database

Tags: javascript, node.js, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

How to trigger a function when UTC server time equals to alertTime in firebase database? This should keep listening to old entries as well as new entries and check if the condition satisfies (UTC server time === alert time) before executing the function.

[image: Firebase database]

Answer (score 2):

You need to somehow parse that date string from Firebase into a standard format. The easiest would probably be to translate the string into a timestamp (milliseconds since January 1, 1970).

So if you have a timestamp value, you can compare to the current UTC timestamp on the server by using `new Date().getTime()`.

**Updated based on comments**:

You can try using [node-schedule](https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-schedule). If you are able to parse the date string, you can create a `Date` object and pass it into the `scheduleJob` API. For example, if you can parse "2018.04.30 at 12:00:00 UTC" to 1525089600000, you can do the following:

```
var schedule = require('node-schedule');
var date = new Date(1525089600000);

var j = schedule.scheduleJob(date, function(){
  console.log('The world is going to end today.');
});
```

Comment: Thanks, What kind of a logic do I have to write to check current time constantly and comparing it with firebase date entries?

Comment: If you want to implement your own solution, read up on timers in Node.js: https://nodejs.org/en/docs/guides/timers-in-node/. You can also use open-source libraries like [node-schedule](https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-schedule).